# How to make sql join query in laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, join

Hi I want to get data from database, I am using join query but I have got this error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'surat_masuk' (SQL: select `jenis_surat`.`jenis_surat`, `surat_masuk`.`nomor_surat`, `surat_masuk`.`perihal`, `surat_masuk`.`tanggal_publish` from `surat_masuk` inner join `jenis_surat` on `id_jenis_surat` = `jenis_surat`.`id_jenis_surat` inner join `surat_masuk` on `id_jenis_surat` = `surat_masuk`.`id_jenis_surat`)

I have 2 tables, surat_masuk and jenis_surat, I want to get jenis_surat field from jenis_surat table and nomor_surat, perihal, tanggal_publish from surat_masuk table. and there is column id_jenis_surat in both table.
This is my query:

```
$surat = new Surat();
    $surats = $surat->join('jenis_surat', 'id_jenis_surat', '=', 'jenis_surat.id_jenis_surat')
                    ->join('surat_masuk', 'id_jenis_surat', '=', 'surat_masuk.id_jenis_surat')
                    ->select('jenis_surat.jenis_surat','surat_masuk.nomor_surat','surat_masuk.perihal','surat_masuk.tanggal_publish')
                    ->get();
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: can you share the relationship beetwen your model jenis_surat and surat_masuk ?

Comment: Which table contain `id_jenis_surat` field in  `'id_jenis_surat', '=', 'jenis_surat.id_jenis_surat'`

Comment: Can you add the pure sql statement that you hope to achieve as a result of the above code?

Comment: 1. SURAT_MASUK : id_jenis_surat, nomor_surat, perihal, tanggal_publish.

2. JENIS_SURAT: id_jenis_surat, jenis_surat.

Comment: Use this way     $surats = $surat->join('jenis_surat', 'surat_masuk.id_jenis_surat', '=', 'jenis_surat.id_jenis_surat')
      ->select('jenis_surat.jenis_surat','surat_masuk.nomor_surat','surat_masuk.perihal','surat_masuk.tanggal_publish')
     ->get();

Comment: Thanks Uttam Kumar Roy! it's works. would you mind to answer in the answer field? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$surats = $surat->join('jenis_surat', 'surat_masuk.id_jenis_surat', '=', 'jenis_surat.id_jenis_surat')
->select('jenis_surat.jenis_surat','surat_masuk.nomor_surat','surat_masuk.periha‌​l','surat_masuk.tanggal_publish')->get();
```

Comment: If it works, you should accept the answer so that other people can be benefited from it. Thank you@hendraspt

Answer (score 0):

```
$surat = new Surat();
$surats = $surat->join('jenis_surat', 'surat_masuk.id_jenis_surat', '=', 'jenis_surat.id_jenis_surat')
->select('jenis_surat.jenis_surat','surat_masuk.nomor_surat','surat_masuk.perihal','surat_masuk.tanggal_publish')
->get();
```

OR

```
$surats = \DB::table('surat_masuk')
->join('jenis_surat', 'surat_masuk.id_jenis_surat', '=','jenis_surat.id_jenis_surat')
->select('jenis_surat.jenis_surat','surat_masuk.nomor_surat','surat_masuk.perihal','surat_masuk.tanggal_publish')
->get();
```