# pivot table result join with another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have these tables:

**packages**
`id`
`package_name`

**package_subject** (pivot table)
`package_id`
`subject_id`

**subjects**
`id`
`subject_name`
`class_id`

**classess**
`id`
`class_name`

I can list all subjects under packages from pivot table using this:

```
$subjects = Subject::whereHas('packages', function ($q) use ($package_id) {
    $q->where('package_id', $package_id);
})->get();
```

I need to get class name associated with the subject, how can i rewrite the above query to get corresponding class name also

Comment: you mean to use the class name as a condition for your `whereHas`?

Comment: ...or do you just want to be able to get the `class_name` that's related to the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you defined classes *relationship* in your Subject model, you can achieve related class objects and their properties right now without any changes in the query.

The issue can be in using reserved "class" word though. I would recommend avoiding such words in names. Use "subjectClass" or sort of.

```php
class SubjectClass extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'classes';
}

...

class Subject extends Model
{

...

  public function subjectClass()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(SubjectClass::class, 'class_id');
  }
}

...

$subjects = Subject::whereHas('packages', function ($q) use ($package_id) {
    $q->where('package_id', $package_id);
})->get();

echo $subjects->first()->subjectClass->class_name;
```

Ou course, there is a space to "eager loading" optimization and alternative approaches here.

Comment: if there is one more level then what to do? eg;- class belongs to some curriculum

Comment: You can repeat the trick in the same way as ...->subjectClass->curriculum->... Or you can use SQL-like joins and an implicit select list of fields like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36759692/272885